# Facebook Pixel lead tracking on button click not consistently being tracked

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

We have put Facebook lead tracking on a form on our website. Using javascript attached to the click of the submit button, we are firing `fbq('track', 'Lead')` as given in the Pixel documentation. We also track these form submissions in our site backend since they are stored in the database. We are seeing a large difference between what we have in our system vs what FB is tracking via the pixel. FB seems to only have - at most - about 50% of the events.

Usually, when I've seen this issue with Google Analytics, it has to do with the asynchronous nature of the tracking event not completely before the form is submitted. Google has a way to use callbacks so that you can wait until the tracking pixel is loaded before doing something else, but I can't find if there is a way to do that with the FB pixel.

I stepped through the javascript code (see below) and I can see that the `fbq` event does get called, and I can see in the Chrome network tab that the tracking pixel gets loaded. However, since I'm debugging, there is plenty of time for the pixel to load. If a normal user is doing so, the pixel might not load quick enough before the form is submitted.

Is this an issue that others have seen? And if so, how can you make sure the tracking event happens synchronously?

HTML submit button:

```
<button type="button" class="submitbutton" onclick="checkForm(fields);">
    <?php echo $submit_text; ?>
</button>
```

JS onclick event:

```
function checkForm(fields) {
  //do a bunch of validation, etc.

  if (typeof fbq === "function") fbq('track', 'Lead');

  document.userform.submit();
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Most reliable and easiest way would likely be to track this from the result page of the form submission ...

Comment: Except that introduces the possibility of someone refreshing that page and tracking duplicates or false values. To me, it would be more accurate if it would work correctly on the click event.

Comment: Then track that via the session, and don't output the tracking code again after the first load ...